# How to pass value from spring controller to javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I am calling controller through javascript function like below and I want to return some value(**controller execution time**) from **controller** to **same javascript function** without using return statement or any other way?

```
function myFunction(){
  var form123 = document.getElementById("myFormSubmit");
  form123 .action="userDetailsList";
  form123 .method="POST";
  form123 .submit();  
}
```

Comment: When you submit a form synchronously spring controller is expected to return a view name and not value.If this form is submitted via ajax call then what you attempt to do might be possible.But your question need to be more elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

```
use GSON package  this will help output a json String
```

import com.google.gson.Gson;

**@ResponseBody** This will not return a view it will return a string to the browser (technically) which jquery will read..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/URLHERE", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String CheckAdapter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
    String a = your Logic here;
    hm.put("string", a);
    return new Gson().toJson(hm);
}
```

This is the ajax part

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URLHERE",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**What is ajax?**
AJAX, or Asynchronous Javascript And XML, is a client side technique for communication with a web server. ... Instead of making a URL request for another whole page, you use JavaScript to talk to the server and receive smaller pieces of information that can range from HTML to other data formats like JSON/XML/Etc